# Need help reducing CPU usage of multi-threaded VB.net program

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have been working on a project while learning vb.net: a multithread proxy checker.  I have it working, and on small tests (lists of 1000 proxies to check) it works just fine.  However, I would like to use it to check lists of 500,000 or more proxies.  When I attempt to do this, I see a very large amount of CPU usage.  I have an AMD FX-8320 with 16GB of ram, just for reference.

All of my code can be viewed on my Github ([click this to visit](https://github.com/Eric904P/Proxy-Checker/)) however I will copy the main important parts here.

Basic flow:

1. User clicks "start" and each thread is started on
   "threadedProxyChecker()"
2. threadedProxyChecker() iterates through all members of the List(Of String) containing all proxies loaded from text file
3. The proxy being tested by each thread is loaded into a temporary List(Of String) so work is not being done twice, and this List(Of String) is protected by a SyncLock. "checkProxy(proxy)" is called, and then the proxy is removed from the temporary List(Of String).
4. The result is recorded to either l1 for working or l2 for failed. (Probably don't need l2, just a count of all failed ones stored in an int?)
5. "performStep()" updates the UI to display working proxies in a ListBox, increments a ProgressBar, and reports percent complete as well as the count of working/unresponsive in a Label.
6. When each thread reaches the end of the list, the total count of working/unresponsive proxies is compared to the size of the list, as a condition for the end of the program.  Thread.Abort() is called after all work is done (I know this is bad, but I'm not sure how else I can do this)

How I check each proxy:

```
Function checkProxy(proxy As String) As Boolean
    Dim myProxy As WebProxy
    Dim Temp As String
    Try
        myProxy = New WebProxy(proxy)
        Dim r As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://azenv.net")
        r.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36"
        r.Timeout = 3000
        r.Proxy = myProxy
        Dim re As HttpWebResponse = r.GetResponse()
        Dim rs As Stream = re.GetResponseStream
        Using sr As New StreamReader(rs)
            Temp = sr.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
        Dim Text = Temp
        rs.Dispose()
        rs.Close()
        r.Abort()
        If Text.Contains("HTTP_HOST = azenv.net") Then
            If Text.Contains("REQUEST_TIME =") Then
                Return True
            End If
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
    Return False
End Function
```

The main code executed by each thread:

```
Private Sub threadedProxyChecker()
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        For Each proxy As String In proxies
            SyncLock curProxLock
                If tmpProx.Contains(proxy) Then
                    GoTo Skip
                Else
                    tmpProx.Add(proxy)
                End If
            End SyncLock
            If Not l2.Contains(proxy) Then
                If Not l1.Contains(proxy) Then
                    If (checkProxy(proxy)) Then
                        performStep(True, proxy)
                        l1.Add(proxy)
                        SyncLock curProxLock
                            tmpProx.Remove(proxy)
                        End SyncLock
                    Else
                        performStep(False, proxy)
                        l2.Add(proxy)
                        SyncLock curProxLock
                            tmpProx.Remove(proxy)
                        End SyncLock
                    End If
                End If
            End If
Skip:
        Next
        If proxies.Count() <= (l1.Count() + l2.Count()) Then
            If Not isBox Then
                SyncLock indexLock
                    MessageBox.Show("Done checking!" & vbNewLine & l1.Count() & " working proxies")
                    isBox = True
                End SyncLock
                Label5.Invoke(Sub()
                                  Label5.Text = "Working: " & l1.Count()
                                  Label5.Update()
                              End Sub)
                Label4.Invoke(Sub()
                                  Label4.Text = "Unresponsive: " & l2.Count()
                                  Label4.Update()
                              End Sub)
            End If
        End If
        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()
    End Sub
```

How threads are started:

```
 Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    isBox = False
    Dim threadCount As Integer = TrackBar1.Value

    For int As Integer = 1 To threadCount Step 1
        d(int.ToString) = New Thread(AddressOf threadedProxyChecker)
        d(int.ToString).IsBackground = True
        d(int.ToString).Start()
    Next
End Sub
```

The "performStep()" method called by "threadedProxyChecker()"

```
Function performStep(bool As Boolean, proxy As String)
    If bool Then
        ListBox2.Invoke(Sub()
                            ListBox2.Items.Add(proxy)
                            ListBox2.TopIndex = ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
                            ListBox2.Update()
                            Label5.Text = "Working: " & l1.Count()
                            Label5.Update()
                        End Sub)
    Else
        Label4.Invoke(Sub()
                          Label4.Text = "Unresponsive: " & l2.Count()
                          Label4.Update()
                      End Sub)
    End If

    count = count + 1

    ProgressBar1.Invoke(Sub()
                            ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
                            ProgressBar1.Update()
                        End Sub)

    Label1.Invoke(Sub()
                      Dim percent As Double = Math.Round((count / proxies.Count() * 100), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
                      Label1.Text = "Progress: " & count & "/" & proxies.Count() & " checked " & "(" & percent & "%)"
                      Label1.Update()
                  End Sub)
    Return True
End Function
```

Any advice on how to make things work more smoothly and/or how to lower CPU usage would be awesome! Thanks :)
-Eric

Comment: Do not ever call `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()` -  the **only** exception to this is if you're trying to crash out of your program and you want to end all threads. Calling `.Abort()` can corrupt the .NET run-time state and you cannot rely on it running correctly afterwards.

Comment: There's also a good chance that you're killing your CPU with all of the `.Invoke` calls. You want to avoid them as much as possible. You should marshall your data from the UI thread, the process on a background thread and then marshall your data back to the UI thread once.

Comment: @Enigmativity how should I terminate my threads then? Will the auto-terminate whenever they reach the end of that method?

Comment: My thought I had was this:

https://pastebin.com/JGR8Gzii

Comment: Yes, they automatically end at the end of their start method. Just keep in mind the cost of starting a thread is massive so don't just start threads for small amounts of work.

Answer (score 1):

Threads performing repetitive tasks should `Sleep` somewhere in their loops to 'yield' processing time to other threads.

Put a `Sleep(1)` statement before the `Next` statement in your loops.

Answer (score 0):

There are two primary uses for threads.

1. Do work in background to keep the UI responsive
2. Do more work in parallel

Judging by your code, I'd say that you are aiming for (2), which means you will increase the CPU load (and that is usually a good thing, an idle CPU is wasted). If your code is using too much CPU, then perhaps you can have a look at lowering the priority of your executable.

```
'Process Priority
Dim CurrentProcess As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess
CurrentProcess.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal
'Thread Priority
Dim CurrentThread As Thread = Thread.CurrentThread
CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal
```

It will still use the same amount of CPU, but it will yield to other processes better.

If you want to optimize your code a bit, I would suggest you have a list of URL:s to check, and your threads do a SyncLock on an index to choose instead.. Something like:

```
Dim ProxyList As New List(Of String) ' The list of URL:s
Dim Index As Integer = 0 ' The index to use by next thread
Dim IndexObject As New Object ' The SyncLock object

' In the thread
Dim Value As String ' The URL we get
SyncLock IndexObject
    If Index >= ProxyList.Count Then Return ' We are at the end, we should bail out
    Value = ProxyList(Index) ' Get the value
    Index += 1 ' Increment the counter
End SyncLock
```

As it is now, each thread does a lot of SyncLock's and lookups, this might make it less CPU hungry.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for the main thread to dole out work to the worker threads, with each directed to look at a specific proxy?  Then you can cut out the lock on the source data structure entirely (avoiding potential contention, which I'm not sure if it would be an issue because I'm not sure how long the work would usually take), and you only need to worry about coalescing the results after the workers are done.